# SQL Server Left Join LIKE unexpected result

Tags: sql-server, left-join, sql-like

I have a LEFT JOIN in my query that works for the majority of the query. I have come across a record which it is not working on and cannot figure out why.

I am doing:

```
SELECT t1.StrSerialNumber, t2.serialNumber

FROM table1 AS T1 

LEFT JOIN
table2 AS t2 ON t1.StrSerialNumber LIKE '%' + t2.serialNumber + '%'
```

...t1.StrSerialNumber could have an extra character on either end. Otherwise, these 2 columns should match.

This is working as expected (or hoped) except for 1 row, which makes me think there could be more.

When I run:

```
select * from t2 where serialNumber like '%' + 'number from t1.StrSerialNumber' + '%'
```

...as a separate query, it DOES return what I am looking for! I can see when querying t2 directly for value LIKE, it is there. It just does not work as part of the JOIN.

All columns in t1 are **not null**, so it is not like there is some other missing info.

I even UPDATED t2.serialNumber, not to match t1.StrSerialNumber, but to make sure there are not spaces in the field, etc.

Any 'gotcha's' for this scenario??

Thank you!!

***EDIT***

Here is an example of where it fails.

The green box at the bottom shows the expected results from the JOIN statement, within the green box in the query itself.

The red box in the query results shows the row where I expect a 'like' match.

The orange box in the workspace is the query that returns the serialNumber that I expect to be in row 42, googleSN column.

The yellow line just shows where I think the serialNumber should be going in the JOIN.

Obviously I do NOT expect a 'like' match for all of the '0' values in invSN.

I hope this makes sense!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qFJE.png)

Comment: if T1 has the extra digits then your `LIKE` needs to be on `t1.StrSerialNumber` not `t2`. Perhaps, `LEFT JOIN
table2 AS t2 ON t2.serialNumber LIKE '%' + t1.StrSerialNumber+ '%'`. Otherwise, we'd need at least a sample dataset and expected results for your query. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: Thank you for the response! Thing is, it is working as-is for 5700+ rows, but not for a few others. Reversing it does not face the join correctly, and nothing joins at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query does not return a subset of the first (abusing the word subset). The LEFT JOIN query wants the t1.SN to be contained in a t2.SN value. The second query wants the t2.SN to be contained in a t1.SN value. So I guess you might have a problem with your requirements.

If the phenomenon you describe is the only problem you have, a simple `OR` will solve the problem:

```
SELECT t1.StrSerialNumber, t2.serialNumber

FROM table1 AS T1 

LEFT JOIN
table2 AS t2 ON t1.StrSerialNumber LIKE '%' + t2.serialNumber + '%'
    OR t2.serialNumber LIKE '%' + t1.StrSerialNumber + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you. The way I understand the LEFT JOIN is that it wants to match t1.StrSerialNumber to something LIKE 'anything in front of' + t2.serialNumber + 'anything after'. Meaning if it finds t2.serialNumber + a character on either end, it will be a match. I do see what you are saying, but it is confusing that it looks correct for most of the results.

Comment: Edited the initial post.

Comment: Thank you, now I can see what I suspected (and written above). Take a look at the green box: removing a leading or trailing character from the left (invSN) yields the right (googleSN) value. Now observe the red box: there is no way to arrive to the googleSN value by removing characters from the invSN value; on the contrary, you must ADD a character (or, equivalently, remove a character from the second value).

Comment: Giorgos, thank you very much! I believe I understand what you are saying and I will need to review in the morning. I will update ASAP tomorrow. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi Giorgos... when I try your work around above, my results go from 5764 (expected) to 57,365. Nope, haha.

Comment: This can be due to the items with SN = 0, try to test with a minimum length, e.g. `... LEFT JOIN ... WHERE LEN(t1.StrSerialNumber) > 5`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!! I got it to work (well, you did).

Comment: Well, thank you for your reply, if you think so then perhaps you should consider accepting the answer as well :-) I have to say, though, that I would be a little concerned if I were you; the roots of this exception should be  understood, or you might be missing something important - or is it just a bug of the existing system?

Comment: Giorgos...this is just the growing pain of someone learning. A beginner, really. All of your suggestions makes sense once I see them. I do this reporting as an aside to my main role. I super appreciate your help. Thank again.